# Where to find font.css file not in source

Tags: drupal, https, fonts, sass

I've inherited a large site and am trying to push it to HTTPS. In testing, I've found a locally saved font saved as a .css file being loaded insecurely that I can't find the reference to searching the page source or template files that seem relevant. It's a Drupal 7 set-up based on Zen-grid theme. I'm assuming some nested file or php doc must be making the call and I'm just not familiar enough with the site yet to know where to look.

Where could it be? The file itself is saved in what appears to be a generated directory, with a generated file name with the sites/default/files/fonts path. Can I overwrite how it's being called somewhere without having to find it?

Comment: Did you check the theme settings? If it is loading from the `sites/default/files` directory that tells me it is a module or theme setting pulling the file in. Is the font file pointing to like a typography.com type of service?

Comment: Yea, that's exactly what it was I ended up realizing! I'm going to write out my process in the answer to resolve as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so as it turned out, it was a webfont being loaded dynamically. The reason I couldn't find the call was because it was configured at the font vendor's website in the customer portal.

Ultimately I needed to reset at what url it expected to be able to load the font from (even though it was local to the site), and reload the fonts directory for it to find it correctly.

Incidentally, I tried to do this before pushing my global HTTPS redirect rules live via the settings.php file. Which seemed to fail because the font vendor attempted to 'validate' the location at the time the fonts were republished. In the end I had to push the fonts up again after the redirect was in place and that time it finally worked.